# Call PostgreSQL function with multiple composite output parameters

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to define a function in PostgreSQL 9.1 that takes multiple INOUT parameters of composite types, but I don't know how to call it.

Eg.

```
CREATE TYPE my_type_a AS (a integer, b float);
CREATE TYPE my_type_b AS (c boolean, d varchar(5));

CREATE FUNCTION my_complex_func(INOUT a my_type_a, INOUT b my_type_b)
RETURNS RECORD
'...'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The definition statements execute just fine, but I don't know how to call this function! I tried:

```
SELECT INTO a, b
    a, b FROM my_complex_func(a, b);
```

but this gives an error:

```
ERROR:  record or row variable cannot be part of multiple-item INTO list
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it has anything to do with your input types, or the number of them.

Don't return a RECORD, return a real composite type (defined with CREATE TYPE).

The error `record or row variable cannot be part of multiple-item INTO list` is because you're trying to nest a ROW inside another ROW.

This should work:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type_a AS (a integer, b float);
CREATE TYPE my_type_b AS (c boolean, d varchar(5));
CREATE TYPE ret_type  AS (w integer, v boolean);

CREATE FUNCTION my_complex_func(INOUT a my_type_a, INOUT b my_type_b)
RETURNS ret_type as $$
 ...
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then you can do:

```
SELECT INTO a, b 
  (x.comp).w, (x.comp).v 
  FROM (select my_complex_func(j, i) as comp) x;
```

---

This concrete example works for me:

```
create type smelly1 as (a integer, b text);
create type smelly2 as (a boolean, b float);
create type rettype as (w integer, v boolean);
create function foo_func(n smelly1, m smelly2) returns rettype as $$
declare
  f_ret rettype;
begin
   f_ret.w := n.a;
   f_ret.v := m.a;
   return f_ret;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select (x.comp).w, (x.comp).v from 
  (select foo_func('(4, hello)'::smelly1, '(true,3.14)'::smelly2) as comp) x;
```

returns:

```
 w | v 
---+---
 4 | t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Oops, forgot write field-name (comp) from subquery (x)

Comment: Yes, but what I need to return is two instances of a complex type (the same type in this case, but could be different). I have to return record when there are OUT parameters: `ERROR:  function result type must be record because of OUT parameters`. Of course, if there's some way to do this without OUT parameters that would be OK, too.

Comment: what are you using the OUT parameters for?

Comment: Whatever you use the OUT params for, you should be able to return in an even-more-composite type :-)

Comment: Yes, I can define another composite type to hold the return value, made up of the existing composite types - but that gets a bit ugly for something so simple in principle. So in this case I ended up splitting up my function into two (so each returns one composite value). Thanks for your help anyway, have a +1.